# Everyone has a hot take of the man

Tags: phrase-meaning

> It’s a complicated story, a tale of an uncompromisingly dedicated
>   father who transferred his own ambitions onto his talented daughter,
>   who monitored and controlled nearly every aspect of her personal and
>   professional life from the day she was born, who never let anyone or
>   anything get in the way of her perfect success, even after the worst
>   tragedy. **Everyone has a hot take of the man.** Most of them are
>   unflattering, if you’re the type of person who cares about that kind
>   of thing—which Mr. Quintanilla is not. Everyone who has ever reported
>   on Selena has a story about his or her own frightening interaction
>   with him. An editor at this magazine has one.

http://www.texasmonthly.com/the-culture/amor-prohibido/#sthash.wAVluySK.dpuf

What does **the bold sentence** mean?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a longer explanation. Apparently "hot take" originated in sports writing.  http://www.psmag.com/books-and-culture/a-brief-history-of-bad-sports-writing-64380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **hot take** is *an opinion based on simplistic moralizing rather than actual thought*.
So, the sentence means that everyone has an opinion on the man that is influenced by their morals.

Comment: Source: Urban Dictionary